# Editing a paragraph

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, orthography

> [image]

> *Error*     *Correction*
> Discipline at public life ensures        (e.g.)       at                 in
> peace and harmony, who in turn          (a)  ______    ______
> offer the required impetous                    (b)  ______    ______
> from the nation's progress.                    (c)  ______    ______

This is a question from my school examination of editing the grammatical mistake.

In (b) I have a doubt that the error is *offer* or *impetous*. In most of the AI Grammar checks, *offer* and *offers* both are marked as correct. The reason why I think that *impetous* is not the answer is because generally these questions are about replacing the incorrect form with correct form and not incorrect spelling to correct spelling.

That *impetous* might be a typo only.

Also, in (c) *from* is the error but I think there are two possible corrections- *for* and *to*. Which one is more accurate?

Comment: There are two errors on line (b), one being the spelling of 'impetus'.

Comment: So offers is the correction?

Comment: **The sentence is a disaster**.  course. :) **Discipline in public life ensures peace and harmony which, in turn, offers the impetus required for a nation to move forward**. For example. I feel very bad for you having to take this exam. [This question will probably be moved to ELL.]

Comment: Btw in (c) why it can't be for

Comment: It probably is meant to be 'for' for (c)

Comment: Also, not sure if it should in fact be "offer" for (b), because "peace and harmony" are two things.

Comment: It's so confusing.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [ell.se]

Comment: 'Peace and harmony' here would probably be seen by most people as a single condition (albeit with two aspects), and many would use notional agreement as with 'Health and safety is our principal concern'. Though I'd write 'Discipline in public life ensures peace and harmony, and this in turn offers the impetus required for the nation to move forward.'

Comment: Spelling mistakes are never grammatical errors. Never ever. That's like saying that someone whose accent gets on your nerves is committing grammatical errors.

Comment: Still lost as to how discipline moves things forward. Other people should have a lot of it, yes, as a requirement in public life. But how does it move? It offers stability, engenders trust, and I admire it. So?